# How to eager load related models when indexing using SearchKick / ElasticSearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, searchkick

This is my `search_data` method:

```
def search_data
  {
    email: email,
    skills: interests.pluck(:name)
  }
end
```

where my `User` `has_many :skills`. When I run `User.where(conditions).reindex` it load the `skills` records like

```
SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skills.user_id = 1
SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skills.user_id = 2
SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skills.user_id = 3
SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skills.user_id = 4
. . .
```

I wonder if it's possible to make it load like this:

```
SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skills.user_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, . . .)
```

Comment: how you found a solution to this?, this makes indexing take a really long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use eager load when indexing, so to reindex your `User` model, you'd write something like `User.includes(:skills).reindex`

Then you'd need to use  `map` instead `pluck` here too:

```
def search_data
  {
    email: email,
    skills: interests.map(&:name)
  }
end
```